# Creating a Vector to filter out multiple rows

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, data-manipulation

I have a data frame with a variable named 'value'.  Within that variable there are numeric ranges (eg 90-94), but there are also ranges with letters in front, such as LT, GE, LE, etc. I want to filter out the rows with the letters in front and only get the number ranges.

At first, I thought a space after the letters in a filter statement would work, but instead, nothing happened.

My specific code chunk:

```
    OHperformance <- OHperformance %>%
      filter(Value != ".",
             Value !="PS", 
             Value !="LT  ", 
             Value !="GE  ",
             Value != "LE  ")
```

Then, I was able to make a vector, but had to label them all individually.

```
    OHperformance <- OHperformance %>%
      filter(!Value %in% c("LT50", "LE5",     "LE20", "LE10", "GE95", "GE90", "GE80", "GE50", ".", "PS"))
```

Is there an easier way to get rid of rows with LE or GE?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example of your dataset and desired output?  Do you want to remove those with alphanumeric values entirely (`OHperformance %>% filter(!grepl("[A-Z]|\\.", value))`), or just modify them such that you keep the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

One way to remove the rows with letters is to see whether if you remove non-numeric characters from `Value` it changes. We can use the regex `"\\D"` to [match non-numeric characters](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html):

> \d: matches any digit. The complement, \D, matches any character that is not a decimal digit.

```r
library(dplyr)
OHperformance  |>
    filter(
        Value == gsub("\\D", "", Value)
    )
#   Value
# 1     9
# 2    10
# 3     7
# 4     8
# 5     6
# 6     3
```

Note - this assumes your column only has integers as it will replace the decimal point. If you have numbers with decimal points, don't replace that either. You could use something like:

```
Value == gsub("[^0-9\\.]|^\\.$", "", Value)
```

This pattern replaces everything except numbers and decimal points, but it will replace a decimal point if it's the entire string.

#### Alternative approach - coerce to `numeric` and drop `NA`

Alternative, as essentially you only want to keep numeric values, you could just coerce the column using `as.numeric()` and drop `NA` values.

```r
OHperformance |>
    filter(!is.na(as.numeric(Value)))
# Same output
```

#### Sample data

```r
OHperformance  <- structure(list(Value = c("LT50", "9", "10", "GE90", "LE5", "7", 
"8", "6", "GE95", "3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```